# OpenGL 4.5 functions segfaulting

Tags: c, windows, opengl, windows-7

I'm trying to write an MCVE OpenGL application in C on Windows 7. I'm finding that OpenGL 4.5 functions specifically, are segfaulting ("access violation") for no reason that I can determine.

My computer is an Nvidia Optimus laptop with a discrete GeForce 765M card which, [according to the Nvidia spec](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-765m/specifications), supports OpenGL 4.5. I have also observed this on Linux by running `primusrun glxgears -info` (with Bumblebee/Primus to allow running applications on the discrete card).

My (Windows) GeForce driver is version 372.70 (latest ATOW).

So, using Visual Studio 15, I have the following minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <gl\GLU.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

typedef struct
{
   GLenum type;
   const char* fileName;
} shader_t;

GLuint vao;
GLuint bufferName;
GLint vPosition = 0;
GLuint program;
GLuint vertex, frag;

shader_t shaders[] = {
   {GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "vertex.glsl"},
   {GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "frag.glsl"}
};

GLuint compileShader(shader_t shader)
{
   GLuint ret = glCreateShader(shader.type);

   FILE* file = fopen(shader.fileName, "r");

   fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
   size_t fileSize = ftell(file);
   fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

   GLchar* src = malloc(fileSize + 1);

   fread(src, 1, fileSize, file);
   src[fileSize] = 0;

   fclose(file);

   glShaderSource(ret, 1, (const GLchar**)&src, NULL);

   free(src);

   glCompileShader(ret);

   GLint compiled;

   glGetShaderiv(ret, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);

   if (!compiled)
   {
      GLsizei len;

      glGetShaderiv(ret, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);

      GLchar* log = malloc(len + 1);
      glGetShaderInfoLog(ret, len, &len, log);
      log[len] = 0;

      fprintf(stderr, "Compile failed: %s", log);
      free(log);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   return ret;
}

void init()
{
   const GLfloat verts[6][2] =
   {
      {-0.90, -0.90},
      { 0.85, -0.90},
      {-0.90,  0.85},
      { 0.90, -0.85},
      { 0.90,  0.90},
      {-0.85,  0.90}
   };

   glCreateBuffers(1, &bufferName); // XXX <- segfault here!
   glNamedBufferStorage(bufferName, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 2, verts, 0);

   program = glCreateProgram();

   vertex = compileShader(shaders[0]);
   frag = compileShader(shaders[1]);

   glUseProgram(program);

   glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
   glBindVertexArray(vao);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferName);
   glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
}

void display()
{
   const GLfloat black[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};

   glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, black);

   glBindVertexArray(vao);
   glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   glfwInit();

   GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Triangles", NULL, NULL);
   assert(window);

   glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
   GLenum glewErr = glewInit();

   if (glewErr != GLEW_OK)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "glewInit returned %d", glewErr);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   if (GLEW_VERSION_4_3)
      printf("OpenGL 4.3 is supported!");

   if (GLEW_VERSION_4_4)
      printf("OpenGL 4.4 is supported!");

   if (GLEW_VERSION_4_5)
      printf("OpenGL 4.5 is supported!");

   init();

   while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
   {
      display();
      glfwSwapBuffers(window);
      glfwPollEvents();
   }

   glfwDestroyWindow(window);
   glfwTerminate();

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I find that the program segfaults/"access violation" at the call to `glCreateBuffers()`, line 84. One thing I noticed during my investigation is that this is a new function to OpenGL 4.5. I decided to test compatibility by adding the GLEW version checks that are in `main()`. The only output from this application before segfaulting is:

```
OpenGL 4.3 is supported!
```

If I replace `glCreateBuffers()` with `glGenBuffers()`, the program does *not* segfault at the same line; instead it dies at the next function call, to `glNamedBufferStorage()`. From the Khronos documentation, I notice that the two segfaulting functions are OpenGL 4.5, whereas `glGenBuffers()` has existed for a while.

Library details:

- GLFW v3.2.1 (latest) binaries from website
- GLEW comes from the Nsight tool (`C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Visual Studio Edition 5.2\Monitor\glew`), recently downloaded

I am at a loss as to what I am (probably) doing wrong; please let me know if I am missing anything!

(And if there's any other information I can give to help diagnose, please leave a comment.)

Comment: Note that with Optimus, Windows will default to using the Intel GPU. You can change that by right clicking -> "Run using GPU" (or something like that) *or* adding an exception in the NVIDIA control panel. Also, I'm not sure if Linux drivers support OpenGL 4.5 yet (mine were at 4.4 IIRC).

Comment: Oh and, the reason they're segfaulting is *probably* that they're `NULL`. Try `printf("FUNC: %p %p\n", glCreateBuffers, glNamedBufferStorage)`.

Comment: "*using Visual Studio 15*" You're using Visual Studio. You ought to be able to step through it in the debugger.

Comment: @NicolBolas It is segfaulting inside a function with no source...

Comment: @TimČas You seem to be correct; thank you! If you would like to submit your comment as a proper answer, I would be happy to accept it. :)

Comment: @Doddy: But some code of yours *called* that function. Or called the caller of that function. At the end of the day, you should be able to pinpoint which function call causes the "segfault".

Comment: http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile_guide.html#compile_options_win32, `GLFW_USE_HYBRID_HPG`

Comment: @NicolBolas In VS, I looked at the call stack dialog which said that symbols were missing, and there were "???" levels. I assumed the segfault took place inside the call.